# Possible forms of template template argument in the template instantiation

Tags: c++, template-templates

One of the possible forms of template parameter is a class template. The C++ standard (C++2003) states that an argument for a template template parameter during the template instantiation is an "id-expression". This non-terminal is rather wide. It allows destructors, overloaded operators, etc. For example the following code should compile fine:

```
template <template <typename x> class T>
struct MyClass
{
    T<int> a;
    T<double> b;
};

template <typename x> struct Helper
{
    ~Helper() { }
    x operator+(x p) { return(x[1]+p); }
    x[4] c;
};

 MyClass<Helper> p1;
 MyClass<~Helper> p2;
 MyClass<Helper::operaror+> p3;
```

The last 2 lines do not make any sense. But from the standpoint of the grammar they are fine. The grammar is not (and should not) describe the language exactly, but the paragraph 14.3.3, "Template template argument" does not mention any restrictions on the grammar rules in this context.

Can anybody embrace or refute my statements:

1. Template template argument can be ONLY an identifier, maybe qualified.
2. If point one is true, this is definitely worth mentioning in the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

14.3 [temp.arg] p1

> "There are three forms of *template-argument*, corresponding to the three forms of *template-parameter*: type, non-type and template. The type and form of each *template-argument* specified in a *template-id* shall match the type and form specified for the corresponding parameter declared by the template in its template-parameter-list.

The argument `~Helper` does not have the right type for the template template parameter `template<typename> class T`, it's not a class template.

14.3.3 [temp.arg.template] p1

> A *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter* shall be the name of a class template, expressed as *id-expression*.

`~Helper` is not the name of a class template.

That pretty clearly rules out your examples.

Comment: I was expecting to see words about the form of the non terminal. They used more high level language: "shall be the name of a class template". This is also acceptable. My bad. In my variant of the C++ grammar I use stricter non terminal in this situation.

Comment: @KirillKobelev, see Annex A [gram] paragraph 1: "_This summary of C++ syntax is intended to be an aid to comprehension. It is not an exact statement
of the language. In particular, the grammar described here accepts a superset of valid C++ constructs._" You need to take the normative wording into account as well as the grammar rules.

Comment: I was mentioning this in the initial post: "The grammar is not (and should not) describe the language exactly" (by the way).